# Photocapture device Camera Hangs in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, barcode-scanner

I am developing an application in Windows Phone 8. Basically in my application, i use `PhotoCaptureDevice` API for taking snaps and scanning Barcodes. When I go forth and come back to camera page continuously using hardware back button sometimes camera page hangs and unable to proceed further.

```
The code snippet used is :

//Passing Videobrush to PhotoCapturedevice

VideoBrush brush;

brush.SetSource(_device);

//PhotoCapture Device Intialization

internal PhotoCaptureDevice _device;

CameraSensorLocation cameraLocation;

    if (PhotoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Back))
    {
          var supportedResolutions = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back);
          _initRes = GetBestResolution(supportedResolutions);
           cameraLocation = CameraSensorLocation.Back;

     }
     else if (PhotoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Front))
     {
           var supportedResolutions = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Front);
           _initRes = GetBestResolution(supportedResolutions);
            cameraLocation = CameraSensorLocation.Front;

     }
```

Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the photocapture object before calling brush.SetSource(_device);